# whats the difference between getLine, readLn and print and putStrLn

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to read 2 values and add them. When I do this:

```
add a b = a + b

main = do
    x <- readLn
    y <- readLn
    let sum = add x y
    print sum
```

it works. But when I do this:

```
add a b = a + b

main = do
    x <- getLine
    y <- getLine
    let sum = add x y
    print sum
```

it doesn't. I would like to know why.

Comment: What are the types of `readLn` and `getLine` (by extension, what are the types of `x` and `y` in either program?). What is the type of `add`? Did you read the type error for the 2nd program? It is probably something like `No instance for Num [Char]` or `Couldn't match Integer with String` - does the error answer your question?

Comment: x and y are integers. So since getLine reads only strings, I can't use it here. Is that it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`getLine` has `getLine :: IO String` type

That's why in this line `x <- getLine`, `x` gets `String` value, but `(+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a` is only defined for `Num` instances.

`readLn :: Read a => IO a` gets the line and `read` the value, i.e. parses a string and returns a value of a particular type.

Thus, `readLn` is the same as `read <$> getLine`.